# AddGesture different in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have no idea why my code isn't working :

```
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "gameofthrones_splash")
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView))
    image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return image
}()
```

This imageView is loaded in the ViewDidLoad (I can see it)

```
func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
    print("123")
}
```

But nothing get returned in the console when I'm tapping on it ! WTF?

Comment: Try to retain the imageView. Instance might be getting released. Initialise image globally and add the gesture to it.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: let image = UIImageView() put it some where else such as viewDidLoad and use image variable inside this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the target. This works when place in the viewDidLoad():

```
profileImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 60, width: 70, height: 70)
view.addSubview(profileImageView)
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView))
profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

The target is "self", which is the UIViewController (not the UIImageView). In most cases (I'm sure there are outliers) you want to record a gesture in a view, but work with the gesture in a view controller.

Comment: No but I just had to add a lazy… It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the solution was quite simple actually. You have to make it a lazy var instead of a let.

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = UIImage(named: "gameofthrones_splash")
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView))
    image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

return image
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0: 
There was some error I removed it - 
Put this code in viewdidLoad

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var profileImageView:UIImageView {
            var image = UIImageView()
            image.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
            image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44)
            image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView))
            image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            return image
        }

        view.addSubview(profileImageView);


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        print("123")
    }
```

Just to test I removed the image, you can add it. But it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using an UIButton ->

```
let profileImageView: UIButton = {
    let iv = UIButton()
    let image = UIImage(named: "r2d2")
    iv.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectProfileImage), for: .touchUpInside)
    iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return iv
}()

@objc func selectProfileImage(){
    print("Hello")
}
```